# C# Classes to List => Loop => Print Out

Tags: c#, list, collections

Hey guys I recently started learning C# using microsoft .Net Tutorials.

I'm stuck at "Classes and Objects" Lesson.
At the end of the each lesson we have a little "homework" to do. 
I need to write a program that prints out addresses for people and companies using three different classes (Person, Copmany, Address). I need to add them to collection and loop through, printing out the address for each company or person.

Here is the [LINK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started/classes-objects) (at the end of the page there is an example how the program should look like.

I'm not really sure how am I suppose to achieve this. Can someone please help me understand. This is what I come so far:

```
public class Address
{
public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }

public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{StreetAddress}, {City}, {PostalCode}, {Country}";
}
public Address()
{
    StreetAddress = "Main123";
    City = "SomeTown";
    State = "OH";
    PostalCode = "12345";
    Country = "United States";
}
}

public class Person : Master
{
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    ShippingAddress = new Address();
}
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{FirstName} {LastName} {ShippingAddress}\n";
}
}

public class Company : Master
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

public Company(string name)
{
    Name = name;
    ShippingAddress = new Address();
}
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{Name} {ShippingAddress}\n";
}
}


public class Master
{
public static List<Master> data = new List<Master>();
public static void Coll(Master master)
{
    data.Add(master);
    data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
}

class MainClass
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person John = new Person("John", "Smith");
    Master.Coll(John);
}
}
```

Comment: please post the code as text and not as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already reached the end of your tutorial, then it means that you have read the section about Inheritance and Polymorphism.
Please read this section again carefully.

If your task is: **printing out the address for each company or person**

Have a look on what the tutorial says about the `ToString` method:

> Note that you can override the ToString method on any class where it will make sense to display string data related to an instance of the class.

So you first step would be to give the class `Address` the ability to display it's content, by overriding the `ToString` method.

You second step would be to use inheritance and create a super class which can be inherited by your 2 classes `Person` and `Company`. As it is done in the tutorial with the class `Shape`.

This will allow you to **to add them to [a single] collection** (as you wrote in your request).

Try to combine these steps and if you still have questions drop me a comment.
(Please keep rereading the tutorial, all the necessary information is in there, you just have to combine the different parts). Good fortune!

EDIT:

After you have edited your code, the next steps would be to give your classes `Person` and `Company` the ability to display information about themselves. Meaning you should override the `ToString` method also there.

One tip : you can use the `ToString` method of the class `Address` to display the details of the `ShippingAddress`. No need to write the details again ;) If you include the variable in the extrapolated string `$"...` the `ToString` method will be called implicitly and display all the details:

```
$"{ShippingAddress}"
```

One problem with your `Coll` method is that it is using a local variable `List<Master> data` as storage. This variable will cease to exist when the compiler returns from the method. Another problem is that in each call you create a new `List` making it impossible to store more than 1 element. What you can do is to make it a `static` variable inside the `Master` class. So that every time you add an item it will stay in memory and can be accessed later on.
You can also make the method `static` since it does not really require an object of type `Master` to be called (it does not access any class properties)

```
public class Master
{
    public static List<Master> data = new List<Master>();

    public static void Coll(Master master)
    {        
        data.Add(master);
        data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

You can call it like this then:

```
Person John = new Person("John", "Smith");
Master.Coll(John);
```

Comment: I would prefer using Interface in this case - something like IAddressable with the only readonly property returning address. I can hardly imagine a good example of a base class and its usages for such entities.

Comment: @soton you are probably right, since a good example for a base class is really not obvious. But interfaces are probably dealt with in the next tutorial ;) I am trying to work with the knowledge OP can pull from the given link. Since they expect him/her to solve this problems with the taught material.

Comment: Thank you! I've made some progress, but the program prints just the name of the Class, not the values like "John Smith", could you please check out my edited code and see what's going on?

Comment: @Nyx it prints the name of the class because it uses the default implementation of the `ToString` method. This default is inherited from the object class and it always simply prints the name of the class. What you need to do is to override it! like you did already in the `Address` class. One in the `Person` and one in the `Company` class

Comment: @MongZhu Thank you so much for helping me! My program is almost done, it prints everything as it should be but as you can see everything is in the same row, I don't know how to implement Console.WriteLine in overriden ToString.

Comment: @Nyx What you are missing is a nice`\n` inside your string. It is called a newline character try it like this:  `return $"{StreetAddress},\n{City}, {PostalCode},\n{Country}";` and `return $"{FirstName} {LastName}\n{ShippingAddress}";`

Comment: Wow thank you! Didn't know about the "\n" thing. Now everything looks great! And most importantly I understood everything you explained me!

Comment: @Nyx Glad to hear that you learned something and even understood me ;-P. another variant of the new line is [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) there is a lot of stuff you can do with strings. Have fun and keep learning it's worth it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straight forward. You can do it using interfaces or polymorphism.

You need put objects into collection, and iterate through all of them.

```
entityList = new List<IPrintable>();
foreach(var entity in entityList)
{
    entity.PrintAddress();
}
```

To achieve this, you need to use common interface for both classes;

```
internal interface IPrintable
{
    void PrintAddress();
}
```

You need to implement this interface in both classes.

```
public class Person : IPrintable
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Person's address is {0}", ShippingAddress.ToString());
    }
}

public class Company : IPrintable
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Company's is {0}", ShippingAddress.ToString());
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(" Street: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, post code{4}, {5}", StreetAddress, City, State, PostalCode, Country);           
    }
}
```

Instead of having common interface you can make abstract base class, which will hold ShippingAddress field and have virtual method Print() without implementation. Then this base class will be type you use in List class
   var entitylist = newList();

```
public abstract class ShippableEntity
{
    private Address _Address;

    private ShippableEntity(Address address)
    {
        _Address = address;
    }

    public abstract void Print();

    public Address ShippingAddress { get { return _Address; } }
}
```

Then you inherit this class in Person and Company and implement Print method in concrete classes.
Then you can do:
    entitylist.Add(new Person(....));
    entitylist.Add(new Company(....));

and do the same thing with foreach as with interface.

You need to call base class constructor!

```
public class Person : ShippableEntity
{
     public Person(Address address)
             : base(adress)
     {
     }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I still haven't learned Interfaces, I'll try your solution as soon as that tutorial comes along.

Comment: I gave you also brief solution with polymorphysm.

Comment: uhm whenever I try to inherit from an abstract class created like you, it says that it does not contain constructor that takes 0 arguments. I'm fairly new with the Abstract classes.

Comment: Huh, I didn't provide you whole solution on a plate. I thought you know how objects are created and handle this.
You need to call base class constructor!

public class Person : ShippableEntity
{
 public Person(Address address)
             : base(adress)
 {
 }
}

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Could I just write "public Address ShippinAddress {get;set}" instead (inside ShippableEntity class)? Also I'm having problem finding a way to implement List, should I make a List inside one of the classes or the Main class? I was able to add an instance to the list but I can't apply "Print" method foreach loop.